# How to make iPhone vibrate using Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, vibration

I need to make the iPhone vibrate, but I don't know how to do that in Swift. I know that in Objective-C, you just write:

```
import AudioToolbox
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

But that is not working for me.

Comment: Swift has the same function available for you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlayAlertSound

Comment: Here you will find all codes for each .caf and associated category : https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary For example if you want a lighter vibration you can use the code 1003.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Short example:

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))            
    }
}
```

load onto your phone and it will vibrate.  You can put it in a function or IBAction as you wish.

### Code Update:

```
 AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) { }
```

As apple code docs written:

> This function will be deprecated in a future release. Use
> AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion instead.

**NOTE:** If vibrate doesn't work. check vibrate is enable in sounds and haptics settings

Comment: is there a way to let the phone to vibrate continuously until a button is pressed?

Comment: What Nicholas asked, also I was wondering if there's a way to make it vibrate in some special pattern.

Comment: @Nicholas You could try to use timers to play kSystemSoundID_Vibrate in sequence  but continuous vibration seems to be a common reason for app store rejection: http://10base-t.com/unofficial-appstore-rejection-criteria/

Comment: I know there's a github that shows the System ID's for all of the iPhone audio files and 3 of the vibrate files, but does anyone know how I can access the OTHER vibrate files? I want to use the Staccato vibrate for instance, but I can't figure out the ID, or even if there is one.

Comment: awesome ... though when I loop the vibrate "sound", it certainly has a threshold (i.e. waits till finishes before vibrating again) ... is there any way around this (i.e. to have the phone constantly buzzing, as opposed to pulsing with a minimal delay between each)?

Comment: @Nicholas if I found an application which asks me to press a button, otherwise it will vibrate forever, I am going to delete it from my device immediately.

Comment: It should be noted, that `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` will play a sound if vibration is not available on the device while `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` won't do that.

Comment: Keep in mind that the device does not vibrate if your app’s audio session is configured with the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord audio session category. This ensures that vibration doesn’t interfere with audio recording.

Comment: Hello @FedeHenze How can I achieve vibration with the audio recording?

Answer (score 90):

**Swift 4.2 Updated**

Just insert code below into your project.

**Usage**

```
Vibration.success.vibrate()
```

**Source Code**

```swift
  enum Vibration {
        case error
        case success
        case warning
        case light
        case medium
        case heavy
        @available(iOS 13.0, *)
        case soft
        @available(iOS 13.0, *)
        case rigid
        case selection
        case oldSchool

        public func vibrate() {
            switch self {
            case .error:
                UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.error)
            case .success:
                UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.success)
            case .warning:
                UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.warning)
            case .light:
                UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
            case .medium:
                UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium).impactOccurred()
            case .heavy:
                UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy).impactOccurred()
            case .soft:
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .soft).impactOccurred()
                }
            case .rigid:
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid).impactOccurred()
                }
            case .selection:
                UISelectionFeedbackGenerator().selectionChanged()
            case .oldSchool:
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add 'import AVFoundation' in order to use .oldSchool vibration :)

Comment: Except .oldSchool remaining cases not working I tested in iPhone 6 physical device any help?

Comment: You should explain that FeedbackGenerator is haptic and it came with iPhone 7.
You can also have only one line each case : 
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy).impactOccurred()

Comment: The only one that's working for me is `.oldSchool`. I'm using an iPhone 6s with iOS 14. The iPhone 6s *does* have a taptic engine and it's used when toggling the silent switch. Is it disabled because Apple want to make the iPhone 7 look better? Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong. **Edit:** Nevermind, Michael's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 82):

In iOS 10 on iPhone 7 or 7 Plus, try:

```
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.impactOccurred()
```

Comment: we all use iOS 10, don't we? it's the newest, the best and free version of the system. everyone should update, there is no compromises of having it.

Comment: Beyond iOS 10, this is only a feature that will work with iPhone 7 or later.  It will be ignored on devices older than the iPhone 7.

Comment: @C6Silver You're true. It isn't working on iPhone 4s,5,5s,5c and 6. These devices I have tested.

Answer (score 62):

Other vibration types:

```
import AudioToolbox

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // Actuate "Peek" feedback (weak boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520) // Actuate "Pop" feedback (strong boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521) // Actuate "Nope" feedback (series of three weak booms)
```

---

Comment: This seems to be the only way of getting haptic feedback on an iPhone 6s

Comment: clicking that link seemed to try to freeze my computer

Comment: @ctm I removed the link. Looks like it was dead. Thank you

Answer (score 33):

**Swift 4.2, 5.0**

```
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
   }
```

You can also choose other styles like

```
    style: .heavy
    style: .medium

    //Note: soft and rigid available in only iOS 13.0
    style: .soft
    style: .rigid
```

Answer (score 26):

For **iOS 10.0+** You can try [UIFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator)

Simple viewController above, just replace your view controller in your test "single view app"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var i = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let btn = UIButton()
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
        btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        btn.setTitle("Tap me!", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func tapped() {
        i += 1
        print("Running \(i)")

        switch i {
        case 1:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.error)

        case 2:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.success)

        case 3:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.warning)

        case 4:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
            generator.impactOccurred()
        case 5:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
            generator.impactOccurred()

        case 6:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
            generator.impactOccurred()

        default:
            let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.selectionChanged()
            i = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

We can do this in Xcode7.1

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can vibrate the phone using either `AudioServices` or `Haptic Feedback`.

```
// AudioServices
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

// Haptic Feedback
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium).impactOccurred()
```

Checkout my open source framework [Haptica](https://github.com/efremidze/Haptica), it supports both `Haptic Feedback`, `AudioServices` and unique vibrations patterns. *Works on Swift 4.2, Xcode 10*

Answer (score 3):

```
import AudioToolbox

extension UIDevice {
    static func vibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    }
}
```

Now you can just call `UIDevice.vibrate()` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

UINotificationFeedbackGenerator available from iOS 10 and work with Haptic v2, we can check this:

```
  let feedbackSupportLevel = UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "_feedbackSupportLevel") as? Int
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *), let feedbackSupportLevel = feedbackSupportLevel, feedbackSupportLevel > 1 {
            do { // 1
                let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
                generator.impactOccurred()
            }

            do { // or 2
                let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
                generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
            }
        } else {
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

Comment: You should highlight in your answer that you are using [`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound) instead of top answer's [`AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405202-audioservicesplayalertsound).

Answer (score 0):

Create Vibrate with AudioTooBox

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

 static func vibrate() {
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
     print("Vibrated")
 }
```

How to generate haptic feedback with UIFeedbackGenerator

```
private let feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light) 
   // FeedbackStyle   //.light //.medium //.heavy


feedbackGenerator.impactOccurred()
```