# How can you make device vibrate at different frequencies using swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to make an app that make phone vibrate at different frequencies. How can I control the frequency of the phone vibrating?

Comment: Here's an answer relevant to what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455880/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-using-swift

Comment: I was looking for something about vibration frequency

Comment: There are no public APIs that allow custom vibration of any kind.

Comment: I was looking for something like this: Cycloramic for iPhone SE/5/5S 
http://tapsla.sh/efEZljp

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps, but in my case I wanted to have longer vibration for some reasons & I created this extension for it.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func vibrate(_ style: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.FeedbackStyle = .heavy) {
        let impactFeedbackgenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: style)
        impactFeedbackgenerator.prepare()
        impactFeedbackgenerator.impactOccurred()
    }

    func vibrateBomb() {
        for i in 0...4 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i * 1)/3) {
                self.vibrate()
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i * 1)/5) {
                self.vibrate()
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i * 1)/8) {
                self.vibrate()
            }
        }
    }
 }
```