# Is it possible to perform vibration from iOS widget?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that we can able to perform vibration from iOS mobile app.

But I need to know whether we can perform vibration from Today extension / **Widget** on some action like a button action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make iPhone vibrate using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455880/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-using-swift)

Comment: @MQLN my question is not general, please read it again, I'm specifically asking for widget not within the app.

Comment: Vibration and haptic feedback are different things. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @matt Thanks for mentioning it, I'm asking about vibration

Comment: @all: Guys I got the answer and I have added it to the answers list for reference. If in case you wonder whether vibration is possible in "Widget", Yes it is. I have tested it.

Answer (score -2):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455880/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-using-swift).

```
import AudioToolbox
//Swift: 
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
//Obj-c: 
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Comment: Thanks for interest, but my question is wether this could be done from the widget. Please let me know if you know wether its possible.