# iPhone not Vibrating

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am using the following source code for the iPhone vibrating.But Its not working in iPhone 6s device. Could any one guide me for do this task in ios swift

```
extension UIDevice {
        static func vibrate() {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
        }
    }

@objc func sos_Tapped(sender: UIButton!) {                        
        UIDevice.vibrate()
}
```

Comment: See the questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/26455880/2112688 about how to make iPhone vibrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned iPhone 6s. You should really consider using [UIFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.