# make phone vibrate on UIButton click

Tags: swift, iphone-vibrate

I was trying to implement vibration functionality on the click of UIButton with following line of code:

```
import AudioToolbox

AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

But nothing happens. if someone has an experience regarding this, please check the issue.

Comment: Where are you calling it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455880/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-using-swift

Comment: Hope you are not testing on iPod. Because iPod don't support vibration.

Comment: @RobertDresler on UIbutton action

Comment: @Torongo testing it on iPhone 7

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using haptic feedback if the device supports it (eg iPhone).

```
let feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
feedbackGenerator.impactOccurred()
```