# How to make a long vibration in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, vibration, audiotoolbox

I want to make a button that you press and your phone vibrates. When you release, the vibration should stop. Ideally, it will have touch sensitivity, so the harder you press, the stronger the buzz.

```swift
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

Currently this just plays 1 buzz, and a loop still has a slight disconnect, but a loop is still an unwanted workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can make the phone vibrate with:

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))            
    }

}
```

(This example is from a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455880/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-using-swift))

If you wanted vibration to be indefinite and continuous, you could use timers to play it in sequence. But apparently, [this is a common cause of app rejection from the App store](http://10base-t.com/unofficial-appstore-rejection-criteria/), so I wouldn't recommend it.

I'm not sure if there's an API for increasing the velocity of haptic feedback/system vibrate.

Comment: I've tried a loop, but it takes a pause between repeating vibrations. kSystemSoundID_Vibrate does like a half second vibration. I have seen it will likely get rejected, however, I am still curious.